# assigning date to each element of a column vector in R

Tags: r

I have a column vector, which embodies the mean monthly rainfall data. I want to assign a date to each element of the column vector. I used `ts (column vector , freq=12,start=c(1901,1)`, but the output I got is not something I want. Rather I needed the form which can be used in "xts' package ....date format like (year/month/date) `1901-01-01 ,1901-02-01 .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create sequences of dates with `seq.Date` (which is a `seq` method that's automatically deployed on `Date` objects) or with `timeBasedSeq` from the `xts` package.

If you're working with `xts` anyway, I'd suggest `timeBasedSeq` for convenience.

For example, the following creates a sequence from `1901-01-01` to `1901-03-15`. The sequence is daily, since we specify `/d`.

```
library(xts)
timeBasedSeq('19010101/19010315/d') 

##  [1] "1901-01-01" "1901-01-02" "1901-01-03" "1901-01-04" "1901-01-05" "1901-01-06"
##  [7] "1901-01-07" "1901-01-08" "1901-01-09" "1901-01-10" "1901-01-11" "1901-01-12"
## [13] "1901-01-13" "1901-01-14" "1901-01-15" "1901-01-16" "1901-01-17" "1901-01-18"
## [19] "1901-01-19" "1901-01-20" "1901-01-21" "1901-01-22" "1901-01-23" "1901-01-24"
## [25] "1901-01-25" "1901-01-26" "1901-01-27" "1901-01-28" "1901-01-29" "1901-01-30"
## [31] "1901-01-31" "1901-02-01" "1901-02-02" "1901-02-03" "1901-02-04" "1901-02-05"
## [37] "1901-02-06" "1901-02-07" "1901-02-08" "1901-02-09" "1901-02-10" "1901-02-11"
## [43] "1901-02-12" "1901-02-13" "1901-02-14" "1901-02-15"
```

See `?timeBasedSeq` for more details.

---

**EDIT**

You can then create your `zoo` or `xts` object by supplying this date sequence as the object's index.

For example, let's create 10 random uniform variates and add an index to create an `xts` time series object, and a `zoo` time series object (the latter is the format of the `SanMartinoPPts` that you mentioned in your comment on this post).

```
x <- runif(10)
x_xts <- xts(x, timeBasedSeq('19010101//d', length=10))
x_zoo <- zoo(x, timeBasedSeq('19010101//d', length=10))

x_xts
##                 [,1]
## 1901-01-01 0.5278193
## 1901-01-02 0.8832607
## 1901-01-03 0.4451737
## 1901-01-04 0.8107669
## 1901-01-05 0.8518433
## 1901-01-06 0.9430592
## 1901-01-07 0.9683322
## 1901-01-08 0.5490602
## 1901-01-09 0.6492584
## 1901-01-10 0.8066997

x_zoo
## 1901-01-01 1901-01-02 1901-01-03 1901-01-04 1901-01-05 1901-01-06 
##  0.5278193  0.8832607  0.4451737  0.8107669  0.8518433  0.9430592 
## 1901-01-07 1901-01-08 1901-01-09 1901-01-10 
##  0.9683322  0.5490602  0.6492584  0.8066997
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable comment    it cleared a part of the murkiness but still I have not been able to fathom the problem that I am facing , ..... ,The method that you wrote allow me to have a column full of desired date sequence and this can assigned to the  rainfall data by merging the two by using" data.frame"  but this is not what I desired  ,I can not post the snapshot of what I need  but It can be seen in the "hydroTSM " package , I need the format in which "SanMartinoPPts" data set is in ..., Thanks again for your comment @jbaums

Comment: @jbaums-- voila , this is what I wanted .....thanks man , sorry I can not up vote  your answers as I do not have 15 reputations at present ..

Answer (score 0):

```
seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1999/1/1"), "years")
```

you can also use shorter intervalls

```
seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2003/1/1"), by="3 months")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable comment    it cleared a part of the murkiness but still I have not been able to fathom the problem that I am facing , ..... ,The method that you wrote allow me to have a column full of desired date sequence and this can assigned to the  rainfall data by merging the two by using" data.frame"  but this is not what I desired  ,I can not post the snapshot of what I need  but It can be seen in the "hydroTSM " package , I need the format in which "SanMartinoPPts" data set is in  which is a part of the hydroTSM package..., Thanks again for your comment @markus Rehm

Answer (score 0):

If this is monthly data you probably want to use `"yearmon"` class rather than `"Date"` class.  Here it is both ways.

If `tt` is the object created in the question, i. e. `tt <- ts(x, freq = 12, start = c(1901 , 1))` where `x` is the data then try this:

```
xt <- as.xts(tt)
```

which uses `"yearmon"` class as the index or if you want a `"Date"` class index

```
time(xt) <- as.Date(time(xt)) ##
```

This also works and gives a `"yearmon"` class index.

```
xt2 <- as.xts( zooreg(x, as.yearmon("1901-01"), freq = 12) )
```

and a `"Date"` class index could be derived from it similarly to `##`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro , things are a bit easy to handle after using your code ... :)